# Make two ImageViews coincident zooming

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have two `ImageView`s on a layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zoom" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `ImageView` with id `zoom` has implemented the [PhotoViewAttacher](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) which makes the `ImageView` zoomable.

The other `ImageView` with id = `drag` has a `OnTouchListener`:

```
drag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            //Definition MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK: Bit mask of the parts of the action code that are the action itself.
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    int i = lParams.leftMargin;
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                            .getLayoutParams();

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;

            }
            viewGroup.invalidate();
            return true;


        }
    });
```

So the drag ImageView is moveable around the screen.

What I want is: If I zoom in, the drag `ImageView` shall be zoomed in too. Same the other way while zooming out.
How can I place the drag `ImageView` in a way that it is "docked" on the zoom `ImageView`. So if I move the zoom image around the screen, the drag image have to stay on the position it left.

For example:

1. drag is moved to center of the screen.
2. zoom is zoomed in
3. zoom moved to right so the drag image is moved outside the screen
4. zoom moved back to the center where the drag image is docked

I hope you understand what I want to do

Kind Regards!!